# How to call back an Object created in Python

Tags: python, list, object, inheritance

I have created several Objects in Python But when I try to recall them back I am Getting an error called "'int' Object has no attribute"

Please consider that Parameters VehicleID,VehPosition,VehSpeed are constantly being updated by a program. What I want is to store all the data in separate Objects.

Here is my code

objectNumber.py

```
class VehicleNumber:

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name= name
    self.SpeedList=[]
    self.PositionList=[]

def set_Speed (self,VehicleSpeed):
    self.SpeedList.append(VehicleSpeed)


def set_Position (self,VehiclePosition):
    self.PositionList.append(VehiclePosition)
```

Here is my Main Class

```
class main :
VList = []
def calculation():
                VehicleID =infVeh.ID # VehicleID is an Integer which is generating from a program each time I run this code ex :- 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 
                VList.append(VehicleID)
                condition = VehicleID in VList

                if ( condition == False) :   
                     VList.append(VehicleID)
                     VehicleID = VehicleNumber('car') 
                     VehicleID.set_Speed(VehSpeed)
                     VehicleID.set_Position(VehPosition) 
                     print(VehicleID.SpeedList)
                     print(VehicleID.PositionList)

                else :
                    VehicleID.set_Speed(VehSpeed)
                    VehicleID.set_Position(VehPosition)
                    print (VehicleID.SpeedList)
```

When I run the Code without else part it runs fine, But When I put the else part back again it is giving me 'int' Object has not attribute 'set_Speed'

My initial Objective was to create a new object for each car which enters to the system and then to update its speed and position.

Thank you very much in Advance

Comment: Inside your `calculation()` function I do not see VehicleId defined. It seems like you are making it an integer somehow rather than an instance of `VehicleNumber`

Comment: Just a short question, in the main file, what is the `VehicleID`? Did u declare it and initialize it to `None` ? The condition is always `False` hence there is no error without `else`

Comment: P.s. `if ( condition == False)` will never be true in your case, and your indentation is a little weird

Comment: Please, can u update your code, seems missing something to do with VehiculeID..?

Comment: @camz thanks. VehicleID is being generated by a program. I did not want to add that part in here Since It will complicate the problem.

Comment: Try to debug your code; `print VehicleID` before the `if` statement and you'll see that it is set to an integer. You don't show the code that sets `VehicleID`, so you should focus there and if you don't show us that code we can't really help you there. You should be assigning an instance of `VehicleNumber` to `VehicleID`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj thanks. VehicleID is an int which is being updated by a program each time this code runs. I did not want to put the whole code in because it will complicate the probem

Comment: Well, if `VehicleID` is an int, as you say, then you can't call `.set_Speed()` on it because `int` objects do not have that method. Your code is expecting a `VehicleNumber`.

Comment: @mhawke VehicleID is an integer. So if the code refers the integer instead of the created object it might give me this error. if so How can I get rid of that Error.( If I create a list of Objects would it help)

Comment: @DrakonianD: how would we know how to get rid of the error when we can't see the code? _If_ the code in `calculation()` is correct, it is clear that it expects a `VehicleNumber` object. Perhaps you need to perform a lookup using the integer ID, or otherwise construct a `VehicleNumber`. Can't help further without the code.

Comment: @mhawke if I call it by VehicleNumber() wouldnt it get confused because there are several objects created

Comment: Is `calculation()` a method of `main` class or a standalone function? Shouldn't it also accept an argument (where does `infVeh` come from)?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo This is a part of a Code which I wrote for a simulation. I am getting VehicleID through the API of the Software . infVeh is the code to extract the data from the simulation

Comment: I mean that `infVeh` should be an argument for the `calculation()` method/function. You are taking it from global scope I guess so it's wrong. Once again is it a method of `main` class or a function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put each object in a dictionary instead of list, and use the identifier **VehicleID** to retrieve the **VehicleNumber** object.

Something like:

```
class VehicleNumber:

    def __init__(self, id_, name):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.name= name
        self.SpeedList=[]
        self.PositionList=[]

    def set_Speed (self,VehicleSpeed):
        self.SpeedList.append(VehicleSpeed)

    def set_Position (self,VehiclePosition):
        self.PositionList.append(VehiclePosition)


__main__:
    VDict = {}
    def calculation(VehicleID, VehSpeed, VehPosition):
        if not VehicleID in VDict:   
            vehicle = VehicleNumber(VehicleID, 'car') 
            vehicle.set_Speed(VehSpeed)
            vehicle.set_Position(VehPosition)
            VDict[VehicleID] = vehicle
            print(vehicle.SpeedList)
            print(vehicle.PositionList)
        else :
            vehicle = VDict.get(VehicleID)
            vehicle.set_Speed(VehSpeed)
            vehicle.set_Position(VehPosition)
            print (vehicle.SpeedList)

    calculation(1, 50, 'home')
    calculation(1, 60, 'work')
    calculation(2, 80, 'other')
    print(VDict.get(1).__dict__)
```

Comment: Thanks Marco I will try this code and let you know. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

The immediate answer to your question is that your "else clause" never defines the **VehicleID**.
The corresponding line in your "if clause" would be:

```
VehicleID = VehicleNumber('car')
```

Doing so allows you to call your setter-methods on vehicleID (which is an instance of VehicleNumber).

As you didn't do a similar instantiation of VehicleNumber in your "else-clause", you won't be able to call its methods either.

Now, just like the others I assume you did not actually paste your entire class. becasue from the snippet you posted it is not clear why VehicleID should be an  to begin with. Are we right to assume that somewhere in you "main-class" define/hand over the VehicleID?

Concering you Conditional-Statement:
why not using something like

```
if VehicleID in VList:
    foo
else:
    bar
```

To sum things up in light of your additional information/edited question, how the following should get you going.

---

```
class Main(object):
    vehicle_id_list = []

    def calculation(self):
        vehicle_id = infVeh.ID # some magical integer that we acept as deu ex machina
        self.vehicle_list.append(vehicle_id)
                condition = VehicleID in VList

        if vehicle_id not in self.vehicle_id_list:   
            vehicle_id_list.append(vehicle_id)
            vehicle = VehicleNumber('car') 
            vehicle.set_Speed(VehSpeed)
            vehicle.set_Position(VehPosition) 
            print(vehicle.SpeedList)
            print(vehicle.PositionList)
        else :
            vehicle = VehicleNumber('car')
            vehicle.set_Speed(VehSpeed)
            vehicle.set_Position(VehPosition)
            print (VehicleID.SpeedList)
```

Now, all you realy care for with you conditional statement is to check if the vehicle id is already in you list or not. if not you want to append it.
After that has been accounted for the if-clause as well as the else-clause do the same thing: calling your setters and print the result.
You might as well shorten this to:

```
if vehicle_id not in self.vehicle_id_list:   
    vehicle_id_list.append(vehicle_id)
vehicle = VehicleNumber('car') 
vehicle.set_Speed(VehSpeed)
vehicle.set_Position(VehPosition) 
print(vehicle.SpeedList)
print(vehicle.PositionList)
```

Besides your original question, you may want to check if you find it usefull to reconsider some of your style choices.

- [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) give some helpful recommendations regarding class and attribute names
- each identation should be [4 spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)
- maybe 'Vehicle' would be more apropiate a class name than VehicleNumber seeing that your object stores far more information about the vehicle..
- accordingly, when you instanciate a particular VehicleNumber (as you do in your "if clause") you may store it in a variable like "vehicle" not "VehicleID".
- unlike many other OO languages python does not encourage setter/getters. For an introduction see [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are confused among `int` vehicle id and your custom class `VehicleNumber` object.

The reason you don't run into errors without else clause is your `if` never gets executed.

Once you do this:

```
VList.append(VehicleID)
```

the condition will never become false. Also in the if clause, you are having

```
VehicleID = VehicleNumber('car')
```

In the else clause however you don't have this object creation. I guess what you want is to operate on this object and not on the integer `VehicleID`.
I suggest you rename it to

```
vehicle = VehicleNumber('car')
```